# ember.js - getting access token using simple auth/torii

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-simple-auth, torii

I am using ember.js, simple auth, and torii for oauth with Spotify. I can currently log in and log out just fine, and looking at resources I can see I am getting an access token from Spotify.

When I log `session.data` as the simple auth docs say, I am getting an Object with all my data in it, including my access token. However, I can't seem to pull out that access token. I have tried `session.data.authenticated` to just access the next level of the object, but that returns an empty object. If I try to get to the `access_token`, I get `undefined` [calling `session.data.access_token`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHFPz.png).

`app/controllers/application.js`:

```
    import Ember from 'ember'

    export default Ember.Controller.extend({
      session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

      actions: {

        login () {
          this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:torii', 'spotify-oauth2-bearer')
          console.log(this.get('session.data'))
        },

        logout () { this.get('session').invalidate() }
      } 

    })
```

`app/authenticators/torii.js`:

```
    import Ember from 'ember'
    import ToriiAuthenticator from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/torii'

    export default ToriiAuthenticator.extend({ torii: Ember.inject.service() })
```

How can I get to my access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session.data.authenticated` is undefined at the time you are logging to console.

`this.get('session').authenticate(...)` is async and returns a promise. By logging to the console right after the call, the authentication might not have completed yet.

Try doing:

```
this.get('session').authenticate(...).then(() => {
  console.log(this.get('session.data.authenticated'));
});
```